# java: new File("", "name") != new File("name") ? (file constructor with empty string)

Tags: java, file, constructor

Noticed this today.

Given that a file named "existing" exists in the PWD of a java process (windows).

```
new File("existing").exists() => true
new File("", "existing").exists() => false
new File(".", "existing").exists() => true
```

I would have anticipated, from the [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) that the system dependent default directory would be "." and these all be true, so this unexpected.

Thoughts?

Thanks!

-roger-

Comment: What do you get if you print out `new File("", "existing").getAbsolutePath()`?

Comment: More fun, on unix: `new File("")` returns the current directory, while `new File("","")` returns the filesystem root... Smells like layers of legacy API...

Comment: appears new File("", "existing").getAbsolutePath => "c:\existing" (not *why* it would be that way for both linux and windows...I am not sure)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two argument constructor expects a parent directory name, so your second line looks for a file whose relative path is "/existing". On a linux type system, "/" is the root (as far as I know), so /existing is very unlikely to exist. On windows, I'm not sure what it interprets that as by default, but if I open up a command line and say `cd /Desktop` (working directory being my user folder) it says it can't find the path specified.

Comment: Fascinating. that must be it then...it really doesn't make that clear LOL.

Answer (score 4):

This is what's happening. But I agree because this is confusing

```
new File("", "test").getAbsolutePath() => /test
new File(".", "test").getAbsolutePath() => ${pwd}/test
```

I have no idea why this is the case because I had assumed it would also be pwd for the first one.

Comment: I don't think there's any more reason to assume it would be PWD than some relatively constant directory.  On *nix systems it's probably `/` but on Windows there's no such filesystem root so it needs to be system dependent.

Comment: I'd rather think that `File(".",...)` maps always to the current directory and not the root or whatever.

Comment: I rather think both do the same thing. But that's just me. :)

Comment: @para: Using "." always *does* map to the current directory.  The behaviour in question is when you use the empty String.

Answer (score 4):

I remember encountering this many moons ago, so I did some digging in the actual source. Here is the relevant source documentation from File.java:

```
/* Note: The two-argument File constructors do not interpret an empty
   parent abstract pathname as the current user directory.  An empty parent
   instead causes the child to be resolved against the system-dependent
   directory defined by the FileSystem.getDefaultParent method.  On Unix
   this default is "/", while on Microsoft Windows it is "\\".  This is required for
   compatibility with the original behavior of this class. */
```

So, the non-obvious behavior appears to be due to legacy reasons.

Comment: When in doubt check the source +1 ;)

Answer (score 1):

From [java.io.File](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
If parent is the empty string then the new File instance is created
by converting child into an abstract pathname and resolving the result
against a system-dependent default directory.
```

There's no mention of what the default directory is.

Comment: Uh, yeah that's exactly the part he's referencing in his post.  The confusion comes from the definition of "system-dependent default directory".

Comment: He's referencing something that doesn't exist in the docs (that the default directory might be ".").

Comment: Hence it being an assumption.

Comment: You haven't corrected his assumption since you haven't said what it *actually* means.  He already knows it doesn't mention what the default directory is, otherwise it probably wouldn't need to be "an assumption."

Comment: Ok, we're getting into semantics now. What my reply says is that the documentation doesn't specify what "default" means (other than being "system dependent"), so making assumptions about it is, at best, fragile.

Comment: Fascinating.  I never would have guessed that in windows, the "system-dependent default directory" would be c:\ (guess I'm too used to "default directory" meaning "current working directory").  so maybe the javadocs should have instead just said "the result is undefined" LOL.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that "" is NOT the same as null.  Thusly

```
new File("", "existing").exists()
```

does not assume the . directory.  As @Dylan Halperin said, on Linux using "" directs to the root / directory, as I found using this code:

```
import java.io.*;
class FileTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) { 
        String nullStr = null;
        File f1 = new File(nullStr, "f1");
        File f2 = new File("", "tmp");
        System.out.println("f1.exists(): " + f1.exists());
        System.out.println("f2.exists(): " + f2.exists());
    }
}
```

Output:

> f1.exists(): true
>   f2.exists(): true

Yes, I had created a file named "f1" in the working directory.