# XMLCorpusReader is not creating a corpus

Tags: python, nltk, corpus

I am learning Natural Language Processing with python's nltk. I want to create a corpus from an XML file i have in my directory. So I used the following code.

```
>> from nltk.corpus import XMLCorpusReader
>> corpus_root = "/Desktop/my_dir/corpus/"
>> wiki = XMLCorpusReader(corpus_root ,'output.xml')
>> wiki.fileids()
>>
```

This code block is supposed to output the fileid as 'output.xml'.But it doesnt return anything and the cursor goes to the next line ">>". 
I have my output.xml in the exact directory as specified in corpus_root.
I have all the permission to read and write to the file 'output.xml'.
I have nltk and all its data installed and has all the specified paths.

What should i do to make it work ?

Answer (score 2):

Let's walk through your code:

```
from nltk.corpus import XMLCorpusReader
corpus_root = "/Desktop/my_dir/corpus/"
```

I'm a bit skeptical of this path name (see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6617625/583834). It probably should be something like `/usr/my_username/Desktop/my_dir/corpus`. Make sure that your path is correct by opening up your terminal window, navigating to your directory and executing `pwd` to get your [absolute path](http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/a/absopath.htm). Then copy it above.

```
wiki = XMLCorpusReader(corpus_root ,'output.xml')
```

`XMLCorpusReader` reads a directory as well as a list of filenames *already existing* in that directory. The second argument here is your input file name, not your output name. (Note the third "how to do it" section [here](https://www.packtpub.com/article/python-text-processing-nltk-20-creating-custom-corpora) for a sample call of the related `WordListCorpusReader`: `reader = WordListCorpusReader('.', ['wordlist'])`)

```
wiki.fileids()
```

It's likely that you're not getting anything from this last line because the previous two lines are not used correctly.