# Downloaded files going missing in Android 4.4.2

Tags: android, file, android-download-manager, android-external-storage

We are using the built-in `DownloadManager` to grab files from our server. If we figure out that there has been an update to that file we delete the local version and re-queue a download from the `DownloadManager`. This only runs when you fully kill and re-start the app (timely updates to files are not the priority, just that we have all the files and that they get updated whenever we notice it). This system works perfectly on all of my personal testing devices, however, when testing in the api 19 emulator or on my co-worker's HTC One the files will download and then disappear (no longer in the app's external data folder). I've figured out that both are version 4.4.2 of android (where my devices are either 4.4.4 or 4.0.4). It's weird because they will stick around for a time, but then random files will disappear.

Here is some code:

*AssetManager setup (setup of output folder)*

```
private AssetManager(Context activity){
    if(singleton != null&&IOUtils.hasExternalStorage() != IOUtils.ExtStorageState_OK){
        return;
    }
    context = activity;

    external = ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(context, "")[0];

    external.mkdirs();

    imageFolder = new File(external,imagePath);

    imageFolder.mkdirs();

    singleton = this;
}
```

*Download code*

```
private static class DownloadObject {
    public String ServerID;
    public String updated_at;
    public Uri image;

    public DownloadObject() {
        super();
    }

    public DownloadObject(String ServerID,String updated_at){
        super();
        this.ServerID = ServerID;
        this.updated_at = updated_at;
    }

    public DownloadObject(Cursor cursor){
        super();
        this.ServerID = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ObjectDao.Properties.ServerID.columnName));
        this.updated_at = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ObjectDao.Properties.UpdatedAt.columnName));
        String imageFile = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ObjectDao.Properties.Image.columnName));
        this.image = Uri.parse(AssetManager.getSingleton().getImageFolder().getPath()).buildUpon().appendPath(imageFile).scheme("file").build();
    }
}

//downloadObjectVector is the fresh list of all objects from the server
//existingObjects is the Cursor from the db that lists all existing object locally
private void SpinOffDownloads(final Vector<DownloadObject> downloadObjectVector,final Cursor existingObjects){
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int count = 0;
            if(existingObjects != null){
                count = existingObjects.getCount();
            }

            if (count>0){
                existingObjects.moveToFirst();
                do{
                    final DownloadObject obj = new DownloadObject(existingObjects);

                    DownloadObject notNeededObject = ArrayUtils.findFirst(downloadObjectVector,new ArrayUtils.Predicate<DownloadObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean evaluate(DownloadObject downloadObject) {
                            return downloadObject.ServerID.equals(obj.ServerID)&&downloadObject.updated_at.compareTo(obj.updated_at) <= 0;
                        }
                    });
                    if (notNeededObject != null){
                        File imageTest = null;
                        if(notNeededObject.image != null) {
                            Uri out = Uri.parse(AssetManager.getSingleton().getImageFolder().getPath()).buildUpon().appendPath(notNeededObject.image.getLastPathSegment()).scheme("file").build();
                            imageTest = new File(out.getPath());
                        }else{
                            Log.v(CLASS_NAME,"object with null image:"+notNeededObject.ServerID);
                        }
                        if (imageTest == null||imageTest.exists()) {
                            downloadObjectVector.remove(notNeededObject);
                        }else{
                            if (imageTest != null&&imageTest.exists()&&SHOULD_REPLACE_FILE){
                                Log.v(CLASS_NAME,"DELETING FILE(missing image):"+imageTest.getAbsolutePath());
                                imageTest.delete();
                            }
                        }
                    }else{
                        File imageTest = null;
                        if(obj.image != null) {
                            imageTest = new File(obj.image.getPath());
                            if (imageTest != null&&imageTest.exists()&&SHOULD_REPLACE_FILE){
                                Log.v(CLASS_NAME,"DELETING FILE(image):"+imageTest.getAbsolutePath());
                                imageTest.delete();
                            }
                        }else{
                            Log.v(CLASS_NAME,"object with null image:"+obj.ServerID);
                        }
                    }
                }while(existingObjects.moveToNext());
            }

            if (existingObjects!= null){
                try{
                    existingObjects.close();
                }catch (Exception e){

                }
            }

            DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            for (int i = 0; i < downloadObjectVector.size(); i++) {
                try {
                    DownloadObject dlObj = downloadObjectVector.get(i);
                    Uri in = dlObj.image;
                    Uri out = Uri.parse(AssetManager.getSingleton().getImageFolder().getPath()).buildUpon().appendPath(in.getLastPathSegment()).scheme("file").build();

                    dm.enqueue(new DownloadManager.Request(in).setDestinationUri(out).setTitle(in.getLastPathSegment()));

                }catch (Exception e){
                    Log.w(CLASS_NAME,"Error with Download queued:",e);
                }
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Please let me know if you need any other information or code!

**EDIT1**

So I decided to elaborate on this a bit more with my testing for this and how the issue manifests itself in the hopes that it will make the picture that much more clear!

I start by loading the app via Android Studio and letting it run long enough to know that all the downloads finish and then I look through the app to see which images are there and which are missing. Most images are there normally. Next I exit the app and use the android task manager to fully kill it. Then I re-launch the app via Android Studio. I then wait to make sure that the downloads finish and watch the LogCat to see what files get deleted manually(normally a couple at maximum). Then I go through the app as see which images are still there/which have been added. It seems that every time new images appear AND new images disappear... And normally the ones that get marked as manually deleted actually get replaced via download properly(i.e. NOT "disappeared").

Please let me know if there are any tests you would like for me to do!

**File Observer Test**

First of all this is the first time I've used a `FileObserver` so if I've done something stupid please point it out. Here is my observer code:

```
external = ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(context, null)[0];

    external.mkdirs();

    fileObserver = new FileObserver(external.getPath(),FileObserver.ALL_EVENTS) {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(final int event, final String relPath) {
            String msg = "???";
            switch (event){
                case FileObserver.DELETE:
                    msg = "FILEOB DELETE relPath:"+relPath;
                    break;
                case FileObserver.DELETE_SELF:
                    msg = "FILEOB DELETE_SELF relPath:"+relPath;
                    break;
                case FileObserver.MODIFY:
                    msg = "FILEOB MODIFY relPath:"+relPath;
                    break;
                case FileObserver.MOVE_SELF:
                    msg = "FILEOB MOVE_SELF relPath:"+relPath;
                    break;
                case FileObserver.MOVED_TO:
                    msg = "FILEOB MOVED_TO relPath:"+relPath;
                    break;
                case FileObserver.MOVED_FROM:
                    msg = "FILEOB MOVED_FROM relPath:"+relPath;
                    break;
                case FileObserver.ATTRIB:
                    msg = "FILEOB ATTRIB relPath:"+relPath;
                    break;
                case FileObserver.CREATE:
                    msg = "FILEOB CREATE relPath:"+relPath;
                    break;

                default:
                    msg = "Unknown event:"+event+" at relPath:"+relPath;
            }
            fileObserverHandler.publish(new LogRecord(Level.INFO,msg));
            fileObserverHandler.flush();
        }

        @Override
        public void startWatching() {
            super.startWatching();
            fileObserverHandler.publish(new LogRecord(Level.INFO,"START WATCHING!!!!"));
            fileObserverHandler.flush();
            Log.v("FileObserver","START WATCHING!!!");
        }
    };
    fileObserver.startWatching();
```

I'm using the handler because at first I didn't have the `startWatching()` override in and wasn't getting any logging at all and the docs say that onEvent happens on its own thread and therefore you should use a handler. It's simply this in the class:

```
public static Handler fileObserverHandler = new ConsoleHandler();
```

The ONLY output I get from this at all is "START WATCHING!!!". So I'm guessing I must have done something wrong, because I see it downloading/deleting things... at least it says it is.

Comment: General comment - your singleton pattern seems kinda nasty. It looks like your AssetManager will be half-initialised on 2nd+ instantiations.

Comment: It could be related to Android 4.4.2 has an issue with writing/saving to external SD card - see [reference](http://support.t-mobile.com/thread/66569) and [patch app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.geeksoft.extcardpatch&hl=en)

Comment: Check download status and reason when it is completed!

Comment: @FabianTamp it's not the best, but I have a context update function and only ever actually use the singleton(it gets setup as one of the first actions of my app.

Comment: @Wildroid I don't believe this is the issue as some of the files are getting written and retained, but I suppose I could be wrong...just not sure how to verify that and what to do about it. Asking our users to root their devices seems extreme.

Comment: @mmlooloo I'm going to allaberate above, but basically the I know that the files were successfully downloaded and then disappeared after the fact.

Comment: @MatthewClark fair enough, good luck with your question.

Comment: @MatthewClark Make sure your external storage on those specific devices have more than enough space for the new package.

Comment: @MichaelOtte How much space do you think it needs? The HTC one I've tested on have several GBs free and the emulator has 100MBs. I'm transferring no more then 25MBs of images, etc.

Comment: "Please let me know if there are any tests you would like for me to do!" create receiver for your download manager and log status and reason columns when your downloads are completed. if all of them is ok you will be sure that your problem is not related to download manager. So you must do other things like using [file observer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver.html) to see which process manipulates your files.

Comment: @mmlooloo I got nothing but STATUS_SUCCESSFUL... since it's so random, what file were you thinking I should observe?

Comment: Put all of your destination in a directory and observe that.

Comment: So I may be doing something wrong, but I'm not getting any logging except that it's started watching... I'll put the code above.

Comment: Did you try `Log.v("FileObserver", msg);` after the switch ? In Android you can log whatever the thread.

Comment: You have it back aswards.  Logic should be download file on successful download delete the original file.  There is now no chance of losing file that wasn't replaced.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you describe sounds like the system is clearing up those files like a cache.

In your call to `getExternalFilesDirs` you use `""`, trying to [creating a `File`/directory with `""` can be problematic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6617584/java-new-file-name-new-filename-file-constructor-with-empty-st).

[Use `null` instead of `""` in your call to `getExternalFilesDirs`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)) see if that helps

replace

```
external = ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(context, "")[0];
```

with

```
external = ContextCompat.getExternalFilesDirs(context, null)[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems this issue may not be related to version 4.4.2 only. After reviewing the Download code over and over, I noticed that the download request does not have a setMimeType setting. Sometimes it appears that DownloadManager deletes files upon completion without setting mime type to download request, on some occasions. By default the server sends the file as its content type as application/x-download. Try adding something like

```
 setMimeType(application/octet-stream);
```

to DownloadManager.Request(in) or whichever mime type that suits the files being downloaded. Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried this, but unfortunately no luck:-/ I even tried setting it accurately to image/png but no luck. Thanks for the answer though!

Answer (score 0):

I think it isn't a problem related with the application logic, but the device you were testing on. I have a tablet with the same problem and I was going crazy... the internal storage (were I save the files) may be damaged...